# Input string was not in a correct format, tried but unable to resolve

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
string fbcTypeNameDate = "", fbcTypeNameID = "",Billfor="";
int TotalQuantity=0,BillId=0;
DateTime BillDate;
string fbrc_FabricID="",fbrc_FabricQuantity="",fbrc_FabricDetail="";
string SupplierName = "", InvoiceNo = "", BillDescription = "";
decimal TotalRate = 0,fbrc_FabricRate=0;
string fbrc_getfabricID = "";
int count = 0, index = 0, counter = 0;
public void fillcomboboxinDataGridView()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select FabricTypeName,FabricID From [tbl_FabricTypeName] ";
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(dt);
    dgv_FabricTypeName.DataSource = dt;
    dgv_FabricTypeName.ValueMember = "FabricID";
    dgv_FabricTypeName.DisplayMember = "FabricTypeName";
}
public void fbcTypeName_fillcomboboxBySupplierName()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SupplierName,SupplierID FROM tbl_SupplierDetails";
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(dt);
    cmbox_PurchaseFabric_SupplierName.DataSource = dt;
    cmbox_PurchaseFabric_SupplierName.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
    cmbox_PurchaseFabric_SupplierName.DisplayMember = "SupplierName";
}
public void getFabricId()
{
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(*)as countid from tbl_FabricBuy  ";
    count= Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if (count==0)
    {
        fbcTypeNameDate = dtp_PurchaseFabric_Date.Text;

        fbcTypeNameID = fbcTypeNameDate + "/FAB/" + 1;
        dataGridView_PurchaseFabric_EnterItemsDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = fbcTypeNameID;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 (FabricID) from tbl_FabricBuy  order by FabricNo desc";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            fbrc_getfabricID = dr["FabricID"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        fbcTypeNameDate = dtp_PurchaseFabric_Date.Text;
        index = fbrc_getfabricID.IndexOf("FAB");
        counter = Convert.ToInt32(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4));
        counter = counter + 1;
        fbcTypeNameID = fbcTypeNameDate + "/FAB/" + counter;
        dataGridView_PurchaseFabric_EnterItemsDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = fbcTypeNameID;
    }

}
```

Input string was not in a correct format, tried all the formats but unable to resolve the problem, so give any suggestion to resolve the problem.

Comment: where(which line) you are getting this error?

Comment: counter = Convert.ToInt32(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4));

Comment: Rule #1 check your inputs

Comment: BTW how does you `FabricID` looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, indexes are zero relative

```
counter = Convert.ToInt32(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 3));
```

Comment: So if the value fab id is "FAB1" and using `index + 4`, you are getting an empty string, which is not a valid integer.  If however, fab id is something like "FABXXX" then it will never be an integerer.

Answer (score 0):

Then it's simple, you have this code:

```
counter = Convert.ToInt32(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4));
```

Which throws and `Incorrect format error` which means that `fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4)` can't be converted to an `Int32`. You may have an error in your index handle, maybe it's +3 instead of +4.

I recommend using this:

```
int output;
if(!Int32.TryParse(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4), out output))
{
    // Handle your error here by applaying default value for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
index = fbrc_getfabricID.IndexOf("FAB");
counter = Convert.ToInt32(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index, index + 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Input string was not in a correct format" will throws only when it failed to convert the type from source type to Destination type, Here it is from string to int. that means the the source is not contains the numbers(or having some characters that are not converted to int)

Here i suggest you to use `Int32.TryParse`

```
int counter;
if(!Int32.TryParse(fbrc_getfabricID.Substring(index + 4), out counter))
{
   //Do your code here, you will get the output to counter if the conversion is successfull
}
```